# Smart way of sending emails from a website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently using SmtpClient to send emails to users that register or sign up for an event.

When they click register it saves the info and calls the send email function, but it takes slightly less than a second to send an email which is too long.

Is there a way to save the users info and after the page is loaded it calls the send email function from vb in the background.

I thought about using a winform to send the emails but where do you run it when I'm using Godaddy for hosting?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the SmtpClient's SendAsync() method vs. the Send() method. This will allow the code to continue past the email send because it spawns a new thread to handle the send. This saves the user the wait. Just don't send 1000s of email in a loop this way. It can cause your server to spawn too many thread and hinder performance.

You can also research the Smtp Service "Pickup Directory" option. If you have file write access to where the SMTP server is located you can 'drop' mail in there to be sent later.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the user info and when the page loads, you can make an ajax call to a server page which will send an email to the user. The advangate of this is, since it is asynchronous, user don't need to wait for this action to be completed for continuing some other action in the site navigation. But it will not be faster than the method you have.

You may use the dom `ready` function to make the ajax call like this, in the (re ?)loaded page.

```
$(function(){

  //Whatever code inside this will be executed only after the DOM finishes loading
   var userId=45;  //replace this with your new userId
   $.post("Emailer.aspx?userId="+userId,function(data){
      alert("Some alert message if you really want!");
   });

});
```

Assuming you have a page called `Emailer.aspx` which will read the querystring parameter and do the action( send email).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use ajax, do you have documentation of the function or an example?

Comment: @MagedAssad: check my updated answer. Use jQuery ajax. you need to include jQuery library to your page to use that. There are tons of tutorials on the internet to learn jQuery ajax

Answer (score 0):

My first answer would be the SendAsync as suggested by nbushnell

If you have the worry of 1000s of emails you could have a "bit" field on the database record for the user then write a Windows Service that reads the users table where the bit is 0, sends the email and then sets the bit to 1

This removes the wait time from the user waiting for the page to load however there will be a delay in them receiving the actual email.